# How to connect JS to HTML from different folder

Tags: javascript

I'm starting on a project using netbeans. I created a Web Page Project and its default .html is called "index". In index.html directory, it has a folder called "WEB-INF". I created a new folder inside of it and call it JavaScripts. Then I created a JS file inside that JavaScripts folder.

Below is my html and JS:

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--
    To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
    To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    and open the template in the editor.
    -->
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>TODO supply a title</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <script src="WEB-INF/JavaScripts/index.js"/>
        </head>
        <body>

        </body>
    </html>
```

JS:

```
     document.write("testabc");
```

Its a very simple JS code but nothing appearing on my browser. How can I properly link JS(from different folder) to HTML? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what was error or problem

Comment: Anything inside WEB-INF cannot be accessed directly. Create the files outside the WEB-INF, there it can be access directly by path.

Comment: Nothing appearing on my browser. The text "testabc" does not appearing.

Comment: `"testabc"` you write in `index.js` file

Comment: Subir, I moved the JavaScripts folder alongside my index.html, and change the script to  <script src="JavaScripts/index.js"/>, still no good. bhargav yes I wrote the "testabc" in the JS file.

Comment: its work on my machine

Comment: `WEB-INF` and `index.html` are same level

Comment: I tried the simplest, <script src="index.js"/>. index.js and index.html same level still does not work. Why?

Comment: When I manually open the index.html file by right clicking it, open with chrome, it works. But when run by netbeans, does not work.